# Adding animations to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I've written some code that essentially animates a sequence of images and adds them to a frame when I run the file.
I want to implement a functionality where I can add this animation to two different areas of a JPanel that has a `BorderLayout` (North and West).

I want to do this using a button but I don't know how to do that. I am new to event handling and layout managers.

How do I go about this?

My code for the animation:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ImageSequence extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private ImageSQPanel imageSQPanel;
    private static int frameNumber = -1;
    private Timer timer;

    private void buildUI(Container container, Image[] arrows) {
        int fps = 10;

        int delay = 1000 / fps;
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        imageSQPanel = new ImageSQPanel(arrows);
        container.add(imageSQPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private synchronized void startAnimation() {
        if (!timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frameNumber++;
        imageSQPanel.repaint();
    }

    class ImageSQPanel extends JPanel {
        Image arrowAnimation[];
        ImageSQPanel(Image[] arrowAnimation) {
            this.arrowAnimation = arrowAnimation;
        }

        //Draw the current frame of animation.
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); //paint background

            //Paint the frame into the image.
            try {
                g.drawImage(arrowAnimation[ImageSequence.frameNumber % 10], 0, 0, this);

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                //On rare occasions, this method can be called
                //when frameNumber is still -1.  Do nothing.
            }
        }
    }

    //Invoked only when this is run as an application.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Image[] waving = new Image[7];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            waving[i - 1] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            "/Users/sarthaksachdeva/Documents/IntelliJ Projects/Animation/src/images/Arrow" + i + ".png");
        }
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageSequenceTimer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        ImageSequence controller = new ImageSequence();
        controller.buildUI(f.getContentPane(), waving);
        controller.startAnimation();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to use action listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) should be your first port of call. If you provide an example of an attempt to utilise those it would be easier to provide additional guidance

Comment: I understand the basic functionality of buttons and action listeners but I highly doubt I know enough to make use of them to add animations to BorderLayout areas.

Comment: Do you know how you might added components to a `BorderLayout`? Just because it's wrapped in a button action doesn't change the how you'd approach the basic problem

Comment: If I need to add a button to the North, I'd do something like JPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

Comment: So, you're embarking on the complex subject of animation before having a fundamental understand of the general API, cool. First though, you're using `private static int frameNumber = -1;`, which seems to indicate that no matter how many instances of `ImageSequence` you have, they should be displaying the same frame of animation, cool, BUT, your `Timer` is then an instance field (`private Timer timer;`) which means each instance of `ImageSequence` can update `frameNumber` independently, meaning that as you increase the number of instances of `ImageSequence`, the animation will speed up

Comment: You're also loading images using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                            "/Users/sarthaksachdeva/Documents/IntelliJ Projects/Animation/src/images/Arrow" + i + ".png");`. So a number of issues. First, `Toolkit#getImage` does not report any errors if the images can't be loaded for some reason and, you're referencing `src` in your code. You should never reference `src`, as it will not exist when the program is bundled into a Jar. Instead, you should investigate the use of `Class#getResource` and `ImageIO.read`